# Application of Bayes' rule to three variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I have three binary variables, $M,R,S$ and the following information:
$$
P(M_o) = p \quad P(M_p) = 1 - p \\
P(R_p) = q \quad P(R_u) = 1 - q \\
$$
where $M$ and $R$ are independent of each other. Further, we know that for $S_i$
$$
P(S_p|M_o, R_p) = 1 \quad P(S_p|M_o, R_u) = \beta \\
P(S_u|M_o, R_p) = 0 \quad P(S_u|M_o, R_u) = 1 - \beta \\
P(S_p|M_p, R_p) = 1 \quad P(S_p|M_p, R_u) = 0 \\
P(S_u|M_p, R_p) = 0 \quad P(S_u|M_p, R_u) = 1.
$$
I want to apply Bayes' rule to get at the following two probabilities: $P(M_o|S_p)$ and $P(R_p|S_p)$. For a bit of context with slight abuse of notation, think of $M_i$ as two different types, where $M_p$ always reveals information about $R_i$ (meaning $S_i = R_i$) while $M_o$ distorts the information (meaning $S_i \neq R_i$) with probability $\beta$. I want to know the probability that we are dealing with the distorting type after having observed the message $S_p$.

I am unsure both of how to approach the problem and whether it contains sufficient information to be solved.

Comment: There are eight potential combined outcomes.  It might be worth finding the probability of each (three are $0$).  For example $P(S_p, M_o, R_u) = \beta p (1-q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first probability, consider that $$P(M_o | S_p) = \frac{P(M_o,S_p)}{P(S_p)}
$$

Besides you can find $P(M_o,S_p)$  applying partitioning on $(M_o,S_p)$ and law of total probability :

$$ P(M_o,S_p) = P(M_o,S_p,R_u) + P(M_o,S_p,R_p) = $$
$$ P(S_p|M_o,R_u) P(M_o,R_u) +  P(S_p|M_o,R_p)  P(M_o,R_p) = $$
$$ P(S_p|M_o,R_u)P(M_o)P(R_u)+ P(S_p|M_o,R_p)P(M_o)P(R_p) = \beta p(1-q)+pq$$

Doing the same with $P(S_p)$ :

$$P(S_p) = P(M_o,S_p)+ P(M_p,S_p) = 
$$
$$P(M_o,S_p) + P(M_p,S_p,R_p) + P(M_p,S_p,R_u) = 
$$
$$\beta p(1-q) +pq+ q(1-p) = \beta p(1-q)+q$$

then, $$ \fbox{$P(M_o | S_p) = \frac{ \beta p(1-q)+pq }{  \beta p(1-q)+q  }$}
$$

Remark : All of this reasoning is possible because of the binary and independence properties of the variables

For the second apply same reasoning.

Comment: @chrstnsn , what do you think about this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't have time to go over it during the weekend. This is very helpful. Am I wrong or is there a term missing after you substitute the values so that the first result should be \beta p(1 - q)  + pq?

Comment: Also, I'm slightly confused why (,) does not show up in the expression of ().

Comment: Because $P(M_p,S_p) = P(M_p,S_p,R_p)+P(M_p,S_p,R_u)$

Comment: yep, you're right ! it is $pq$ not $0$, I update